# Add file path to entity programmatically

Tags: 7, entities, files

I am creating an entity programatically, I want to set a file in entity, I have tried following method.

```
$file_path = '/sites/default/files/abc123.pdf';
$values = array(
      'type' => 'review',
      'uid' => $user->uid,
      'status' => 1,
      'comment' => 0,
      'promote' => 0,
    );
  $tenant_review_entity = entity_create('node', $values);
  $tenant_review = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $tenant_review_entity);
  $tenant_review->title->set($_POST['field_tenant_review_ref']['und']['form']['title']);

  // adding file here
  $tenant_review->field_tenancy_document->file->set($file_path);

  $tenant_review->save();
```

If I am adding file path then getting following error

```
EntityMetadataWrapperException: Invalid data value given. Be sure it matches the required data type and format. in EntityDrupalWrapper->set() (line 737 of /var/www/html/rentspeak/sites/all/modules/entity/includes/entity.wrapper.inc).
```

If The file attaching code commented then entity is saving properly.
Please suggest me where is the mistake. Thanks.